# Problems using a background image to create a shadow in a CSS layout

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I am studying on a tutorial how create a fixed tabless CSS layout starting from Photoshop to HTML+CSS code.

This is the final example proposed bu the tutorial (how it have to look like at the end):

http://www.html.it/articoli/1688/template/11-css.html

and this is my personal version of the previous template: http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/

How can you see I have some problem in Firefox with the left shadow of the left column (with others browser I have others problems)

As in the example template I have create this shadow by setting the **bgpage.gif** immage as background of the #container div and putting it on the right of this div

## container {

```
/* /* consente di posizionare un elemento al centro del suo contenitore (non tutti i browser la supportano) */
margin: 0 auto;
width: 770px;   /* Imposto la larghezza */
background: url(../images/bgpage.gif) repeat-y scroll 100% 0 transparent;
```

}

why in the example proposed by the tutorial work well and in mine don't work?

Someone can help me to solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Hi, Andrea! Where should be the image shadow?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your page occurs because two images are overlapping. To be more precise:

`bg4.jpg` in the `body` is overlapped with `bgnarrowcolumn.jpg` in the `#container`.

To fix it, just add these CSS rules:

```
background: url(../images/bgpage.gif) repeat-y scroll 103% 0 transparent;
```

Change the 100% to 103%.

As I could see, in the tutorial page are using this method (I mean, using images to make a background). Let me say that this way to make a website and make the presentation of a webpage is obsolete and is very difficult; as you saw. Besides, you will have accesses to the server, as many images are needed (bad practice).

Why you need to use images? In my opinion a best way is using CSS3:

Here's a Jsfiddle of an example with shadow: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xSm67/)

And if you want to make a gradient background, just add the `gradient` property.

Comment: Tnx, I didn't know these CSS3 property that I can use to create shadwo without background immage, I will try :-)

But, related to your solution seems don't work. I have change to 103% in #container but don't work and seems to me that in the tutorial example this is setted to 100% and not to 103% as you say